# How to define decimal places for a field in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, decimal

I have this field in a model in ASP.NET

```
public decimal myValue { get; set; }
```

And I need it to accept up to 6 decimal places, but the form validator only accepts 2 places.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a try with Regular Expression in the model

`[RegularExpression(@"^\d.\d{6,6}?$")]
public decimal myValue { get; set; }`

and in your view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myValue)
```

Comment: Did the newly edited answer worked? Use of RegularExpression attribute. I feel we can achieve this is using 1. Display format attribute with editor template to handle decimal value 2. Using Regular Exp like above in model 3. Handle directly in client side Jquery Validation but again using regex pattern.